# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Tags: syntax, if-statement, php

I looked at many other questions, but I can't find my own answer in it.
here is my syntax error (unexpeted T_IF):

```
while(($rij1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1))
and( if ($voornaam=NULL) {
            $rij2 = ' ';}
elseif($voornaam!=NULL){
            $rij2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2);})
```

I looked at the line before the syntax, but I couldn't find what is wrong...
Does someone know it?

Comment: What's with the `and` and `if` there? `and` expects expressions as its operands, not statements. What are you trying to do?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rewriting your code as:

```
while ($rij1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1))
{
    if ($voornaam === NULL) 
    {
        $rij2 = ' ';
    } 
    else
    {
        $rij2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2);
    }
}
```

Edit: Corrected your condition in the first `if`, as @andrewsi spotted - `=` is an assignment operator, so previously your code was changing `$voornaam` to `NULL`, then checking if the result evaluated to `true` (which, of course, it never would - so the second block would always execute)

In your original code, you're using the `and` operator - presumably having seen it used in some well meaning but poorly coded examples like `mysql_connect(...) or die('an error occurred');`.

What's happening in that example is that the result of the first statement - `mysql_connect()` - is checked. If it evaluates to true, the second statement never executes, but if it evaluates to false then the second statement - `die('an error occurred');` - is executed. As you've just discovered, this pattern is confusing and best avoided.

Comment: The if statement should be `if ($voornaam==NULL) {`

Comment: +1 Proper indenting makes code so much more readable

Comment: thank you all, haha sorry I don't do this often... But now I got a syntax error on line 22, an unexpected '{' (line 22 is the first line here)

Comment: @user1813397 Your code also had an extraneous `(` in the `while` statement, which caused that error - I've removed it in my latest edit.

Comment: okay thank you all! It works all fine now!

Comment: @KelvinMackay: The else-if was sense-less (always true), also compare with NULL with `===` three. If you keep some little space in there, it's more clear. Just for the code here, you don't need to write code that way at home.

Comment: @hakre Thanks, you're right that scans much better. I'll keep that in mind in future :)